# onUpdate() of AppWidgetProvider not called by given time?

Tags: android, widget

I am working on widget app,in widget xml i declare attribute android:updatePeriodMillis="1000" , means onUpdate will call after every 1000ms.

But it's not calling automatically,

pls let me know why it's happening?

Comment: The minimum update time is 30 min (as of 1.6 I think).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078122/android-widget-not-updating

Comment: @ethrbunny : thanks, but i seen no of widget like : anolog clock which update on every second..

Comment: You can run a thread with whatever update frequency you want.. but using the system 'updatePeriod' has limitations. I think its to keep a widget from eating the battery.

Comment: @ethrbunny : yes i did same , but in android doc they mention this attribute used to update widget after giving time.30 min default it's true.